# Will Magento version 1.4.2.0 work with MySQL version 5.6?

Tags: database, magento-1.4

We have MySQL version 5.5 installed on our server and plan to upgrade to version 5.6. However, we have an old website using Magento version 1.4.2.0. Does anybody know of any issues with this version of MySQL and an old version of Magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can assure you there is no difference if you run your magento 1.4 with mysql 5.5 or 5.6, but it will work.

you will have to use magento 1.9 or 2.0 with at least php 7.0 or hhvm to feel the difference.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) We aren't looking for any gains in performance - our host is upgrading and we have around 30 WordPress and Magento websites on the server that need checking for compatibility issues before the upgrade. @MagenX

Answer (score 1):

Will work with 5.5, 5.6.
However, Magento 1.4.x is very outdated, no longer supported by latest patches. Careful running that version.